# Repeat a PHP Include in the same spot

Tags: php, html, loops, include

I'm working on some HTML wireframes.

There is some HTML code I'd like to be able to repeat 'X' number of times.

e.g.

```
<li>my list item</li>
```

So I put that code into a separate PHP file called "myListItem.php". And then in my main HTML template. I have some code that looks like this:

```
<ul>
<?php include('myListItem.php');?>
<?php include('myListItem.php');?>
<?php include('myListItem.php');?>
<?php include('myListItem.php');?>
</ul>
```

This feels redundant.

**Is there a simple way to repeat the inclusion of the same file 'X' number of times?**

Ideally, I'd be able to have something like the following in my HTML template:

```
<ul>
<?php include('myListItem.php'); myItem(4);?>
</ul>
```

Just figuring out this stuff, so I apologize for what must be an obvious question to many. Keep in mind of course that the code I'm repeating in real-life is actually much longer than a simple list item, which in my example is humorously shorter that the php include itself.

Comment: If it were me, I'd rather capture the result of `include` in some variable, then output it in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < XXX; $i++) { include('myListItem.php'); }
```

Comment: Would you suggest this over creating a UDF?

Comment: it's a quick 'n dirty one-liner. I tend to not make a function of something unless it's "complicated" or used in a huge number of places.

Comment: Fair. Just curious the overhead - 4 `include` vs. UDF with loop.

Comment: probably a little cheaper this way, since there's no function call overhead. either way you'd still be executing 4 includes, though the 2nd and later includes would gain a bit from system cache and whatnot. but this'd hold for both methods anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You are right - *this is redundant*. From your description, including the same file 4 times is the wrong way to solve this problem.

Suitable alternatives would be:

- Extract all logic to the included so you can simply do the following:

  ```
  <ul>
  <?php include('myListItem.php');?>
  </ul>
  ```
- Create [a function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) within your included file

  ```
  <?php include('myListItem.php');?>
  <!-- other code... -->
  <ul>
  <?php displayListItems(4); ?>
  </ul>
  ```

Either way, you are only including the file once.

Comment: how would i write a function that accomplished this?

Comment: I'd need to know what `myListItem.php` does. Either update your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) include('myListItem.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Looking at other answers, I think you're missing the curly brackets around include?